# Problem with Grails GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am developing an application which queries data from an XML file and creates multiple objects with that data.

```
class Search {String artist}

class Performance {static belongsTo = [events:Event, artists:Artist]}

class Location {static belongsTo = [events:Event]}

class Event {static hasMany = [performances:Performance]}

class Artist {static hasMany = [performances:Performance]}
```

This are the domain classes (for the sake of simplicity only relationships are shown).
Then I want to create instances of this objects when the user inserts a new artist in the SearchController. I tried to do that with the following code for the save closure in the SearchController but it seems that it's not working. The resultList is a Map with the values queried from the XML file.

```
def save = {
    def searchInstance = new Search(params)
    def resultsList = searchService.lastFmVenues(params.artist)

    resultsList.each{
        def performanceInstance = new Performance()
        def locationInstance = new Location(venue:it.venue, street:it.street, city:it.city, postcode:it.postalcode, country:it.country, lat:it.lat, lng:it.lng)
        def artistInstance = new Artist(name:params.artist).addToPerformances(performanceInstance)
        def eventInstance = new Event(eventId:it.eventID, title:it.eventTitle, date:it.date, location:locationInstance)

        if (searchInstance.save(flush:true) && eventInstance.save(flush: true) && artistInstance.save(flush: true) && locationInstance.save(flush: true) && performanceInstance.save(flush:true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'search.label', default: 'Search'), searchInstance.id])}"
        }
        else {
               render(view: "create", model: [searchInstance: searchInstance])
           }
    }
    redirect(action: "show", id: searchInstance.id)
}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's "not working" about it? Is it simply that the instances don't get saved? If that's the case, have you verified that there are no validation errors on any of the domains?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I suppose that the instances don't get saved. When I go to the event/list page after I've created a new instance in the SearchController, the event instances doesn't show up on the table. What do you mean by validation errors? Sorry, I'm new in Grails.

Comment: The typical idiom is to call something like `if(domain.validate() && domain.save())`; the `save()` won't work if there are validation errors, which would indicate a violation of the `constraints` closure on the domain.

Comment: I'd highly recommend writing a unit test around this.  And asserting that everything is what you expect.  It will help you find your errors quicker than you think.

Comment: Check this http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/7.%20Validation.html#7.2%20Validating%20Constraints and this http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html. And you can `save()` only top level object: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html, though you'd better use `failOnError` `save()` parameter: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving your objects with `save(failOnError: true)`.  This will cause grails to throw an exception if the objects don't validate.  The default behavior is to simply return false from the save method.

You can make failOnError the default behavior by setting `grails.gorm.failOnError=true` in your `Config.groovy`, but I wouldn't recommend it for anything besides troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks very much! By saving the objects with failOnError I could detect the errors. Apparently the problem was with the Performance class. Instead of: static belongsTo = [events:Event, artists:Artist]    I had to do: static belongsTo = [Event, Artist]. I can't fully understand the difference. Can some one explain it to me?

Comment: @BrunoMorgado :  `belongsTo = [Event, Artist]` creates a uni-directional relation, where as  `belongsTo = [events:Event, artists:Artist]` creates a bi-directional relation